# Selected row, make changes to first and last cell borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a basic table, and would like the selected row to have a border on the left side of the first cell, and on the right side of the last cell. This will be an indicator to the user that the row is currently selected.

I can change the background color of a cell - so I know it is possible to do it with javascript the way that I intend to; I just need the right property to change for the border effect to take place.

Thank you!

I have made a mockup for you to have a look at:

```js
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("example");
    
    
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                        
                                        row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
                                        row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.border = "black solid 2px;";
                                        
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;
                                        alert("id:" + id);
                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

```html
<div>
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: you need to use `borderLeft` and `borderRight` in javascript. see my snippet below

Comment: Hello Mihai T, the solution is exactly what I want; How do I clear the previous row's border, every time a consecutive row is selected? Only one row should have the borders at a certain time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `borderLeft` and `borderRight` in javascript.

see my snippet below . let me know if it helps

```js
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("example");
    
    
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
            function(row) 
            {
                return function() { 
                                        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                                        
                                        row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
                                        row.firstElementChild.style.borderLeft = "black solid 2px";
                                        row.lastElementChild.style.borderRight = "black solid 2px";
                                        var id = cell.innerHTML;
                                        alert("id:" + id);
                                 };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

```css
tr td:first-child { border-left:2px solid transparent;}
tr td:last-child { border-right:2px solid transparent;}
```

```html
<div>
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```